# Azure: Deploy VM in another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm new to Azure and trying to setup an automation.
My questions is, is it possible to deploy virtual machine in another tenant using arm template? I saw these two links in Azure, but did not give me clear idea how I can use that. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/share-images-across-tenants
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11151

Scenario: Two tenants, tenantA and tenantB. I have SIG setup in tenantA and I want to be able to deploy VM in tenantB using image from SIG in tenantA. I'm currently using Azure Java SDK to do so but I was wondering if I can do it using ARM template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, follow the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/share-images-across-tenants to share the VM image with tenant B.

Once that is done, you can reference this quickstart to create an ARM template using the shared image https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-sig/